# TrimRight everything after delimiter

Tags: go

I have a float64 I converted into a string: `30.060671`

I'm trying to trim/remove/chomp everything after `30`

Some of the things I've tried:

```
fmt.Println(strings.TrimRight("30.060671", ".([0-9])"))
fmt.Println(strings.TrimRight("30.060671", "."))
fmt.Println(strings.TrimSuffix("30.060671", "."))
```

Comment: Can't you just round the float before converting it into a string? If not, just slice the string up to the index of `.`.

Comment: E.g. `s1 := fmt.Sprintf("%.0f", math.Pi); s2 := fmt.Sprintf("%.3f" math.Pi)` gives "3" and "3.142".

Answer (score 30):

One way to do it would be to use strings.Split on the period:

```
parts := strings.Split("30.060671", ".")
fmt.Println(parts[0])
```

Another option is to convert to an int first and then to a string:

```
a := 30.060671
b := int(a)    
fmt.Println(b)
```

Comment: If you know you only need the first part you can do `prefix := strings.Split("30.060671", ".")[0]`.

Answer (score 11):

As per @pайтфолд suggested in comment, you should have rounded the **float** before converting to **string**.

Anyway, here is my attempt using **strings.Index** to trim the remaining from `.`:

```
func trimStringFromDot(s string) string {
    if idx := strings.Index(s, "."); idx != -1 {
        return s[:idx]
    }
    return s
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/gWM_6M9t_D)

Also, to answer why **TrimRight** and **TrimSuffix** not working as expected is because `.` is not a trailing string/unicode:

> TrimRight returns a slice of the string s, with all trailing Unicode
>   code points contained in cutset removed.
>
> TrimSuffix returns s without the provided trailing suffix string. If s
>   doesn't end with suffix, s is returned unchanged.

Comment: I like this answer! To complete the answer to the question in the topic, use `strings.LastIndex(s, ".")` to get the last index of the delimiter.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how to get either side of a delimiter.

After Go.18 use [`strings.Cut`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Cut)

```golang
string := "Symver.0.1.0"
delimiter := "."

leftOfDelimiter, rightOfDelimiter, found := strings.Cut(string, delimiter)

fmt.Println("Left of Delimiter: ", leftOfDelimiter)
fmt.Println("Right of Delimiter: ", rightOfDelimiter)
fmt.Println("Found: ", found)

//Left of Delimiter:  Symver
//Right of Delimiter:  0.1.0
//Found:  true
```

https://go.dev/play/p/tS4RpBKlxiV

Before Go1.18

```golang
string := "Symver.0.1.0"
delimiter := "."

leftOfDelimiter := strings.Split(string, delimiter)[0]
rightOfDelimiter := strings.Join(strings.Split(string, delimiter)[1:], delimiter)

fmt.Println("Left of Delimiter: ", leftOfDelimiter)
fmt.Println("Right of Delimiter: ", rightOfDelimiter)   

//Left of Delimiter:  Symver
//Right of Delimiter:  0.1.0
```

https://play.golang.org/p/HBi4G5tBL9

Comment: Be careful: what if your string does not contain the delimiter? Then Split would not have size 2 or more... Anyhow, good unit tests should catch the problem, but still.

Comment: Go now porvides a helper function for this: strings.Cut

Answer (score 3):

### Go provides a function for this: strings.Cut

```
before,after,found := strings.Cut("123.456", ".")
```

You can just use before and ignore the rest:

```
before,_,_ := strings.Cut("123.456", ".")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%.0f", 30.060671))
```

That oughtta do it easy. (BTW: Just to add, one of the commenters originally stated or alluded to a similar solution).
However must you only use string, this should do -

```
   fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%.0f", 30.060671))
    value := "30.060671"
    f := func(c rune) bool {
        return c == ',' || c == ':' || c == '.'
        }
     fields := strings.FieldsFunc(value, f)[0]
    fmt.Printf("%v", fields)
```

You have choice of delimiters there. I don't know if this is elegant but hey.